# How can I confirm the range of unsigned char in C?

Tags: c, char, integer, range, unsigned

The unsigned char for my compiler contains 1 byte.

So as per my knowledge the range of unsigned char is from 0 to 2^8 - 1 which is 255.

Now I want to confirm the max integer unsigned char can display is 255.

The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("unsigned char has %d bytes.\n", sizeof(unsigned char));

    unsigned char a;

    a = 0;

    printf("%d\n", a - 1); 
    printf("%u\n", a - 1); 
    printf("%lu\n", a - 1); 
    printf("%llu\n", a - 1);   
    printf("%zu\n", a - 1); 

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
unsigned char has 1 bytes.
-1
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295 
4294967295
```

4294967295 is 2^32 - 1

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I would have looked at [the value of UCHAR_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_integer_types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, when you pass an integer argument smaller than `int` to a variadic function (like `printf`) then it's automatically promoted to an `int`.

Secondly, when you use arithmetic, smaller integer types *again* are promoted to `int`.

Read e.g. [this implicit conversion reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) for more information.

If you want to print the `char` (or rather `unsigned char`) value you need to use the `hh` prefix for the format specifier (see e.g. [this `printf` and family reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)):

```
printf("%hhu\n", (unsigned char) (a - 1));
```

Comment: The `hh` length modifier is not needed at all. As you correctly say, `(unsigned char)(a - 1)` is promoted to `int` when passed to `printf`, with the same value. `%u` is OK, and `%d` would do too except for rare architectures where `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Conversely, if you insist on using the `hh` length modifier, a simpler approach will do: `printf("%hhu\n", -1);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a-1
```

This is arithmetic operation and implicit conversion takes place. Compiler will treat it as integer. Try to assign -1 to unsigned type, then check the value. You should also notice the printf operands, like %d, which for that particular example, expects integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your knowledge is incomplete in subtle ways:

> The `unsigned char` for my compiler contains 1 byte.

Type `unsigned char` is *by definition* exactly one byte for all compilers.

> So as per my knowledge the range of unsigned char is from 0 to 2^8 - 1 which is `255`.

Not exactly: the *minimum* number of value bits for `unsigned char` is `8` and no padding bits are allowed for this type, which means the *minimum* size for a *byte* is 8 bits. Indeed most architectures nowadays standardize on 8-bit bytes, but the C Standard allows for other, larger, bit widths, and some micro-controllers use 16-bit bytes (or even 32-bit bytes). On such processors, `unsigned char` as 16 bits (or even 32 bits).

> Now I want to confirm the max integer `unsigned char` can display is `255`.

This is a genuine concern that can be validated both at compile time and at runtime.

> The following is my code:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <limits.h>
> ```

Including `<limits.h>` is a good approach: `UCHAR_MAX` is the value you want to print or even test directly in a preprocessing directive.

> ```
> int main(void) {
>     printf("unsigned char has %d bytes.\n", sizeof(unsigned char));
> ```

Undefined behavior: `%d` expects an argument of type `int`, which is different and potentially incompatible with `sizeof(unsigned char)` that has type `size_t`. Use `%zu` or cast the argument as `(int)sizeof(unsigned char)`. Note however that `sizeof(unsigned char)` **by definition** always evaluates to `1` with type `size_t`.

> ```
>     unsigned char a;
>     a = 0;
>     printf("%d\n", a - 1);
> ```

`a - 1` always evaluates to `-1` as `a` is promoted to `int` and `0 - 1` has a value of `-1`. You want instead to print `(unsigned char)(a - 1)`, or simply `(unsigned char)-1`.

> ```
>     printf("%u\n", a - 1);
> ```

This will print the value of `(unsigned int)-1`, which is `UINT_MAX`, not `UCHAR_MAX`.

> ```
>     printf("%lu\n", a - 1); 
>     printf("%llu\n", a - 1);   
>     printf("%zu\n", a - 1);
> ```

The 3 `printf` calls above have potential undefined behavior because you pass an `int` value for an argument whose expected byte is respectively `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` and `size_t`.

> ```
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Here is a simpler approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    printf("UCHAR_MAX = %u\n", UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("(unsigned char)-1 = %u\n", (unsigned char)-1);
    printf("-1 with %%hhu conversion: %hhu\n", -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
UCHAR_MAX = 255
(unsigned char)-1 = 255
-1 with %hhu conversion: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because You have used wrong format specifier of printf.

GCC Compiler warnings:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:32: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("unsigned char has %d bytes.\n", sizeof(unsigned char));
                               ~^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               %ld
prog.c:13:15: warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%lu\n", a - 1);
             ~~^     ~~~~~
             %u
prog.c:14:16: warning: format '%llu' expects argument of type 'long long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%llu\n", a - 1);
             ~~~^     ~~~~~
             %u
prog.c:15:15: warning: format '%zu' expects argument of type 'size_t', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%zu\n", a - 1);
             ~~^     ~~~~~
             %u
```

**C11 $7.19.6.1 p9 :**

> [...] If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.